# Spring boot application not loading the Swagger rest services due to circular references

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

We have a Spring Boot application with 300 Rest Services for which we are trying to generate a Swagger Documentation. We integrated Swagger and added the required Json parameters to the Pojos. When we start the application the server not starts up even after 15 mins or so and when we look at the log it displays in the below format.

```
2019-07-29 10:43:20,299 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Adding collectionElement type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/timetable/TimeTableTuesdayPeriod;
2019-07-29 10:43:20,299 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Recursively resolving dependencies for collectionElement type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/timetable/TimeTableTuesdayPeriod;
2019-07-29 10:43:20,300 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Adding type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/Period; for parameter period
2019-07-29 10:43:20,300 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Recursively resolving dependencies for type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/Period;
2019-07-29 10:43:20,300 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Adding type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/PeriodTimeTable; for parameter periodTimeTable
2019-07-29 10:43:20,301 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Recursively resolving dependencies for type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/PeriodTimeTable;
2019-07-29 10:43:20,301 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Adding type Ljava/util/Set<Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/timetable/TimeTableWednesdayPeriod;>; for parameter timeTableWednesdayPeriod
2019-07-29 10:43:20,301 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Adding collectionElement type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/timetable/TimeTableWednesdayPeriod;
2019-07-29 10:43:20,301 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Recursively resolving dependencies for collectionElement type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/timetable/TimeTableWednesdayPeriod;
2019-07-29 10:43:20,302 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Adding type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/Period; for parameter period
2019-07-29 10:43:20,302 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Recursively resolving dependencies for type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/Period;
2019-07-29 10:43:20,302 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Adding type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/PeriodTimeTable; for parameter periodTimeTable
2019-07-29 10:43:20,303 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Recursively resolving dependencies for type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/PeriodTimeTable;
2019-07-29 10:43:20,303 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Adding type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/PeriodTimeTable; for parameter periodTimeTable
2019-07-29 10:43:20,304 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Recursively resolving dependencies for type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/PeriodTimeTable;
2019-07-29 10:43:20,304 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Adding type Ljava/util/Set<Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/timetable/TimeTableSaturdayPeriod;>; for parameter timeTableSaturdayPeriod
2019-07-29 10:43:20,305 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Adding collectionElement type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/timetable/TimeTableSaturdayPeriod;
2019-07-29 10:43:20,305 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Recursively resolving dependencies for collectionElement type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/timetable/TimeTableSaturdayPeriod;
2019-07-29 10:43:20,306 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Adding type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/Period; for parameter period
2019-07-29 10:43:20,306 DEBUG springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider [main] Recursively resolving dependencies for type Lcom/test/google/model/section/period/Period;
```

Seems like the application recursively trying to access the same objects again and again making it a circular reference issue.

Below is the code and annotations we used for Pojos:

```
@Entity(name="sections")
@JsonIdentityInfo(scope=Section.class,generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Section implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, length=19)
    private long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="section")
    private Set<ReportCardTemplate> reportCardTemplate;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="section")
    private Set<Admission> admission;
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="section_type_id", nullable=false)
    private SectionType sectionType;


@Entity(name="report_card_templates")
@JsonIdentityInfo(scope=ReportCardTemplate.class, generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class ReportCardTemplate implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, length=19)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="section_id", nullable=false)
    private Section section;


@Entity(name="admissions")
@JsonIdentityInfo(scope=Admission.class,generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Admission implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, length=19)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="actor_id", nullable=false)
    private Actor actor;
    @OneToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="subject_preference_id", nullable=false)
    private StudentSubjectPreference studentSubjectPreference;
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="section_id", nullable=false)
    private Section section;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="admission")
    private Set<ExamSubjectMark> examSubjectMark;
```

Any help with the issue is much appreciated....  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)` annotation on the circular dependencies

```java
...
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
private Section section;
```